# Google says "Text too small to read", but no info about recommended font size?

Tags: html, css, seo

While testing my website with google webmaster tools, I'm getting a "Text too small to read" error for 4 pages for mobile, the strange thing is that these pages don't contain any smaller text than on the main page, but errors reported only on those.

I've tried to search for some "minimum font size recommendations" but couldn't find anything.
Are there any design standards or better tools which will provide more detailed reports?

The main page: https://blockchaintd.com/

One of the pages with the error reported: https://blockchaintd.com/category/crypto-for-beginners

Comment: it may be caused by the bottom-menu on mobile? what i found is that the minimum recommended size is 12px, there font-size is at 10px

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll try to increase it, strange that error didn't occur on other pages.

Also, you'll do a big favor by sharing some source where I can read about that specifications :)

Comment: ah sorry about that! well, i came across [this so question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/102813/minimum-font-size-for-mobile-view), which links to [this article](https://www.thinkwithgoogle.com/intl/en-gb/consumer-insights/build-a-great-user-experience/) and there's also [this google lighthouse article](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/font-sizes) which states: "Aim to have a font size of at least 12px on at least 60% of the text on your pages."

Comment: there's also [this article](https://www.wearediagram.com/blog/resolving-mobile-usability-errors-in-google-webmaster-tools) which recommends a px size of 16 for mobile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google's recommendations about text font size says its minimum should be 12px to guarantee readability.

Check this for more: [Document Doesn't Use Legible Font Sizes](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/font-sizes)

Comment: My font was 12 all the time, but I still get the warning from Google.

Comment: Same for me... Very annoying

Answer (score 1):

Google recommends 16px minimum for font size. Below 16px, the text is not readable.

You can find this information on Google Fonts :

> Make sure your text isn’t too small. The exact dimensions of font sizes can vary depending on the unit used, the size of the viewport (if units are relative), and the pixel density of the device’s screen, but a safe bet would be to use **16px or 1em or 1rem** as the smallest size for body type.

Source : https://fonts.google.com/knowledge/readability_and_accessibility/introducing_accessibility_in_typography

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35030024)

Comment: But thanks, anyways, interesting to read))